# Access Append Query compare with table

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert

I am currently rebuilding a messy Access Database and I entcountered the following problem:

I've got a Table of facilities which contain a row called district. Those Rows contain a number linked to another table which just contains the numbers and names of districts. I added a lookup Column with the Name of the district displayed.

I now want to change the new column for every row depending on the data in the old row.

**Facilities**

```
NAME|..|DISTRICT_OLD
A   |..|           1
B   |..|           2
C   |..|           1
...
```

**DISTRICTS**

```
ID|NAME
1 |EAST
2 |WEST
...
```

I would like something like the following:
**Facilities**

```
NAME|..|DISTRICT_OLD|DISTRICT
A   |..|           1|EAST
B   |..|           2|WEST
C   |..|           1|EAST
...
```

The District Field (lookup) gets its Data like follows `SELECT [DISTRICTS].ID, [DISTRICTS].NAME FROM DISTRICTS ORDER BY [NAME];`

(Thanks to Gordon Linoff) I could get the query but I do now struggle with the insert. I can get the Data I want:

```
SELECT [DISTRICTS].NAME FROM Facilities INNER JOIN DISTRICTS ON Facilities.DISTRICT_OLD = [DISTRICTS].ID;
```

If I try to `INSERT INTO Facilities(DISTRICT)` It says Typerror.
How can I modify the data to be compatible with a lookup column?
I guess I need to select the ID as well which isnt't a problem but then the error says to many columns.

I hope I haven't mistaken any names, my Access isn't running the english language.

Can you help me?

Fabian

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup columns are number (long integer)

with a relational database, you only need the single column containing the ID (as you always lookup the district.name with a query) so:

```
INSERT INTO Facilities(DISTRICT) SELECT 4
```

where 4 is the ID of the record in the lookup table that you want, or better still:

```
INSERT INTO Facilities(DISTRICT) 
    SELECT ID FROM DISTRICTS 
        where District.Name = "Name you want the ID for"
```